# How to create a requirements.txt file in Django project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, anaconda, requirements.txt

I have been trying to create a requirements.txt file from the Pycharm terminal but it is adding all unnecessary packages as well. What should I do to show only used packages?
Thanks,
requirements.txt:

> aiohttp==3.7.3
> aioredis==1.3.1 alabaster==0.7.12 anaconda-client==1.7.2
> anaconda-navigator==1.9.12 anaconda-project==0.8.3 appdirs==1.4.4
> appnope==0.1.0 argh==0.26.2 asgiref==3.3.1 asn1crypto==1.3.0
> astroid==2.4.2 astropy==4.0.1.post1 async-timeout==3.0.1
> atomicwrites==1.4.0 attrs==19.1.0 autobahn==21.2.1 Automat==20.2.0
> autopep8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/autopep8_1592412889138/work
> Babel==2.8.0 backcall==0.1.0 backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
> backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0 backports.tempfile==1.0
> backports.weakref==1.0.post1 bcrypt==3.1.7 beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
> bitarray @ file:///C:/ci/bitarray_1594751092677/work bkcharts==0.2
> bleach==3.1.0 bokeh @ file:///C:/ci/bokeh_1593183652752/work
> boto==2.49.0 Bottleneck==1.3.2 brotlipy==0.7.0 bs4==0.0.1
> certifi==2020.6.20 cffi==1.13.1 channels==3.0.3 channels-redis==3.2.0
> chardet==3.0.4 cheroot==8.5.2 Click==7.0 cloudpickle @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cloudpickle_1594141588948/work
> clyent==1.2.2 colorama==0.4.4 comtypes==1.1.7 conda==4.8.3
> conda-build==3.18.11 conda-package-handling==1.7.0 conda-verify==3.4.2
> constantly==15.1.0 contextlib2==0.6.0.post1 cryptography==3.4.6
> cycler==0.10.0 Cython @ file:///C:/ci/cython_1594830140812/work
> cytoolz==0.10.1 daphne==3.0.1 dask @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/dask-core_1594156306305/work
> decorator==4.4.0 defusedxml==0.6.0 diff-match-patch @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/diff-match-patch_1594828741838/work
> distlib==0.3.1 distributed @
> file:///C:/ci/distributed_1594747837674/work dj-database-url==0.5.0
> dj-rest-auth==2.1.3 Django==3.1.5 django-admin-honeypot==1.1.0
> django-allauth==0.44.0 django-bootstrap4==0.0.5 django-channels==0.7.0
> django-crispy-forms==1.11.0 django-defender==0.8.0
> django-heroku==0.3.1 django-honeypot==0.9.0 django-tastypie==0.14.3
> djangorestframework==3.12.2 dnspython==1.15.0 docutils==0.16
> entrypoints==0.3 et-xmlfile==1.0.1 Faker==0.8.13 fastcache==1.1.0
> filelock==3.0.12 flake8==3.7.8 Flask==0.12.4 Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
> Flask-Cors==3.0.3 Flask-JWT-Extended==3.7.0 Flask-Login==0.4.0
> fsspec==0.7.4 future==0.18.2 gevent @
> file:///C:/ci/gevent_1593010772244/work glob2==0.7 gmpy2==2.0.8
> greenlet==0.4.16 gunicorn==20.0.4 h5py==2.10.0 HeapDict==1.0.1
> hiredis==1.1.0 html5lib @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/html5lib_1593446221756/work
> hyperlink==21.0.0 idna @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work imageio @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/imageio_1594161405741/work imagesize==1.2.0
> importlib-metadata==0.23 incremental==17.5.0 intervaltree @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/intervaltree_1594361675072/work
> ipykernel==5.1.3 ipython==7.8.0 ipython-genutils==0.2.0
> ipywidgets==7.5.1 isort==5.7.0 itsdangerous==1.1.0
> jaraco.functools==3.1.0 jdcal==1.4.1 jedi==0.15.1 Jinja2==2.10.3
> joblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/joblib_1594236160679/work
> json5==0.9.5 jsonschema==3.1.1 jupyter==1.0.0 jupyter-client==5.3.1
> jupyter-console==6.0.0 jupyter-core==4.4.0 jupyterlab==2.1.5
> jupyterlab-server @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_server_1594164409481/work
> keyring @ file:///C:/ci/keyring_1593109210108/work kiwisolver==1.2.0
> lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3 libarchive-c==2.9 llvmlite==0.32.1
> locket==0.2.0 lxml @ file:///C:/ci/lxml_1594826940903/work
> MarkupSafe==1.1.1 matplotlib @
> file:///C:/ci/matplotlib-base_1592844891112/work mccabe==0.6.1
> menuinst==1.4.16 mistune==0.8.4 mkl-fft==1.1.0 mkl-random==1.1.1
> mkl-service==2.3.0 mock==4.0.2 more-itertools==7.2.0 mpmath==1.1.0
> msgpack==1.0.0 multidict==5.0.2 multipledispatch==0.6.0
> navigator-updater==0.2.1 nbconvert==5.6.0 nbformat==4.4.0 networkx @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/networkx_1594377231366/work nltk @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nltk_1592496090529/work node==0.9.25
> nose==1.3.7 notebook==6.0.1 numba==0.49.1 numexpr==2.7.1 numpy==1.18.5
> numpydoc @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/numpydoc_1594166760263/work
> oauthlib==3.1.0 odict==1.7.0 olefile==0.46 openpyxl @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/openpyxl_1594167385094/work packaging==20.4
> pandas @ file:///C:/ci/pandas_1592841744841/work pandocfilters==1.4.2
> paramiko==2.7.1 parso==0.5.1 partd==1.1.0 path==13.1.0 pathlib2==2.3.5
> pathtools==0.1.2 patsy==0.5.1 pep8==1.7.1 pexpect==4.7.0
> pickleshare==0.7.5 Pillow @ file:///C:/ci/pillow_1594304973959/work
> pipenv==2020.11.15 pkginfo==1.5.0.1 pluggy==0.6.0 plumber==1.6
> ply==3.11 prometheus-client==0.7.1 prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
> psutil==5.7.0 psycopg2==2.8.6 ptyprocess==0.6.0 py==1.8.0
> pyasn1==0.4.8 pyasn1-modules==0.2.8 pycodestyle==2.5.0 pycosat==0.6.3
> pycparser==2.19 pycurl==7.43.0.5 pydocstyle @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pydocstyle_1592848020240/work
> pyflakes==2.1.1 pygame==2.0.1 Pygments==2.4.2 PyHamcrest==2.0.2
> PyJWT==1.7.1 pylint==2.6.0 pymongo==3.7.2 PyNaCl @
> file:///C:/ci/pynacl_1595009196976/work pyodbc===4.0.0-unsupported
> pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1594392929924/work
> pyparsing==2.4.7 PyQt5==5.15.2 PyQt5-sip==12.8.1 pyreadline==2.1
> pyrsistent==0.15.4 PySocks==1.7.1 pytest==3.3.0 pytest-flask==0.11.0
> python-dateutil==2.8.0 python-decouple==3.4 python-jsonrpc-server @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-jsonrpc-server_1594397536060/work
> python-language-server @
> file:///C:/ci/python-language-server_1594154480810/work
> python-mimeparse==1.6.0 python3-openid==3.2.0 pytz==2020.1
> PyWavelets==1.1.1 pywin32==227 pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0 pywinpty==0.5.7
> PyYAML==5.3.1 pyzmq @
> file:///C:/Users/Rashidov/Desktop/mflix-python/pyzmq-22.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
> QDarkStyle==2.8.1 QtAwesome==0.7.2 qtconsole==4.5.5 QtPy==1.9.0
> redis==3.5.3 regex @ file:///C:/ci/regex_1593435678736/work requests @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1592841827918/work
> requests-oauthlib==1.3.0 rope==0.17.0 Rtree==0.9.4
> ruamel-yaml==0.15.87 scikit-image==0.16.2 scikit-learn @
> file:///C:/ci/scikit-learn_1592863447244/work scipy @
> file:///C:/ci/scipy_1592916961137/work seaborn==0.10.1
> selenium==3.141.0 Send2Trash==1.5.0 service-identity==18.1.0
> simplegeneric==0.8.1 simplejson==3.17.2 singledispatch==3.4.0.3
> sip==4.19.13 six==1.12.0 snowballstemmer==2.0.0
> sortedcollections==1.2.1 sortedcontainers==2.2.2 soupsieve==2.0.1
> Sphinx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinx_1594223420021/work
> sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2 sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
> sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.3 sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
> sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3 sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.4
> sphinxcontrib-websupport @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-websupport_1593446360927/work
> spyder @ file:///C:/ci/spyder_1594820234642/work spyder-kernels @
> file:///C:/ci/spyder-kernels_1594744028846/work SQLAlchemy @
> file:///C:/ci/sqlalchemy_1593446777599/work sqlparse==0.4.1
> statsmodels==0.11.1 sympy @ file:///C:/ci/sympy_1594234724630/work
> tables==3.6.1 tblib==1.6.0 telepot==12.7 terminado==0.8.3
> testpath==0.4.2 text-unidecode==1.2 textblob==0.15.3 threadpoolctl @
> file:///tmp/tmp9twdgx9k/threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
> toml==0.10.2 toolz==0.10.0 tornado==6.0.3 tqdm @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1593446365756/work traitlets==4.3.3
> Twisted @
> file:///C:/Users/Rashidov/Desktop/chat_app/Twisted-20.3.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
> txaio==21.2.1 typing-extensions @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1592847887441/work
> ujson==1.35 unicodecsv==0.14.1 urllib3==1.25.9 virtualenv==20.3.0
> virtualenv-clone==0.5.4 watchdog @
> file:///C:/ci/watchdog_1593447396356/work wcwidth==0.1.7 web.py==0.62
> webencodings==0.5.1 Werkzeug==0.16.0 whitenoise==5.2.0
> widgetsnbextension==3.5.1 win-inet-pton==1.1.0
> win-unicode-console==0.5 wincertstore==0.2 wrapt==1.12.1 xlrd==1.2.0
> XlsxWriter==1.2.9 xlwings==0.19.5 xlwt==1.3.0 xmltodict==0.12.0 yapf @
> file:///tmp/build/80754af9/yapf_1593528177422/work yarl==1.6.3
> zict==2.0.0 zipp==0.6.0 zope.component==4.6.2
> zope.deferredimport==4.3.1 zope.deprecation==4.4.0 zope.event==4.4
> zope.hookable==5.0.1 zope.interface==4.7.1 zope.lifecycleevent==4.3
> zope.proxy==4.3.5

Comment: Assuming you have a venv - you can destroy the venv -> build a new venv -> install only the packages you need -> run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create a file with just the needed packages

Comment: Do you run command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` inside venv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `python -m pip freeze` or `pip freeze` to show only used packages.

And create file with command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: The first command doesn't install freeze. Notice that the line doesn't contain the word "install". That line runs the pip module and passes in freeze as an arg. It's identical to calling `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/)

Especially the command *sfood-imports* which finds and lists import statements in python project

So it is not depended on your env but rather on the code that you wrote

The [readme](https://github.com/blais/snakefood/blob/master/README.rst#:%7E:text=Python%2D3.x%20is%20NOT%20supported%2C%20but%20there%20have%20been%20a%20few%20efforts%20to%20port%20to%20it.%20I%20never%20had%20time%20to%20fully%20port%20it%3B%20it%20would%20require%20a%20fair%20bit%20of%20a%20rewrite%20to%20do%20so%20IMO.) file in the repo says that Snakefood does not support python v3.x. So, be cautious before using.

Answer (score 0):

With **"pipreqs"**, you can create **a requirements.txt** in Django project:

So, install **"pipreqs"**:

```
pip install pipreqs
```

Then, run this short command below in the root directory of your Django project to create **a requirements.txt**:

```
pipreqs
```